# What is the impact of an invitation letter on a fellowship application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, invitations

I applied for a Fulbright scholarship as a non-US resident, for a research visit in the US.

I obtained an invitation letter from one of the top Professors in the field, from a public university in California.

During my Fulbright interview I was asked whether I would still accept the fellowship if I was not matched with the inviting institution. My answer was *Yes*. However, the more I think about this, I get confused as to why would they think of sending me somewhere else. I always thought that an invitation letter makes things easier for all parties involved. Maybe some of you who have participated in admission commissions can elaborate on this.

I can think of two reasons about why I was asked that question:

- the interviewer wants to learn to what extent the candidate is keen to be part of the program.
- the budget of the program might not suffice covering the living costs of someone in California.

Also the interviewers were not experts in the field, so probably the name and work of the inviting Professor was not relevant to them. I also did not make any extra effort to highlight that.

Comment: I doubt that either of your points is the reason. I suspect it is just benign and lets them keep flexible if you are. Whether saying no helps or hurts you, I can't say. I would answer it honestly.

Comment: @Buffy That's what I did, but I would prefer being sent somewhere where I have many years of collaboration and matching research interest, compared to somewhere else...

Comment: I think it is fair an honest if you express your concerns in a future correspondence. Paraphrasing Einstein, be as flexible as possible, but not more. Good luck with it. I assume that if you are offered a different position instead you could still do some negotiating.